# Assign a manually written array to a variable created before

Tags: c++, arrays

How to assign a manually written array to a variable created before.

For example:
**a.h**

```
class PredefinedMatrices {
public:
    PredefinedMatrices();

    unsigned char getSBoxValue(unsigned char hexNumber) const;

private:
    unsigned char sbox[256];
};
```

**a.c**

```
PredefinedMatrices::PredefinedMatrices() {
    sbox[256] = //Sure it won't work
    {
        0x34, 0x5b,
        0x93, 0xc2
    };
}
unsigned char PredefinedMatrices::getSBoxValue(unsigned char hexNumber) const {
    return sbox[hexNumber];
}
```

Assigning the values in the class directly won't work.
It didn't work doing that:

```
unsigned char *matrice;
matrice = new unsigned char[256]{...};
```

I don't want to do a memcpy of a temp matrice into the matrice I need either because of additional allocation time and memory consumption.

Edit: The manually written array is the S-Box from AES encryption. I can calculate it dynamically but I don't want to waste processor cycles for something that is constant and we know the values for.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Comment: From my experience with STL containers the performance impact is pretty evident and I try to avoid the overhead. At the same time, the array is constant so there should not be any difference. I won't move or operate on it, just get values from it.

Comment: Why are there only 4 elements in the array in your suggested initialisation code? Is that just a reduced example, or do you want to somehow only initialise the first four elements or something like that?

Comment: It is a reduced form example. The actual array is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box#Forward_S-box

Comment: @MoraruLilian Then initialize a static array somewhere and pass pointers to it around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I did this:
**a.h**

```
class PredefinedMatrices {
public:
    PredefinedMatrices();

    unsigned char getSBoxValue(unsigned char hexNumber) const;

private:
    static const unsigned char sbox[256]; //I use const only to allow the compiler to optimize the code better
};
```

**a.cpp**

```
PredefinedMatrices::PredefinedMatrices() {}

const unsigned char PredefinedMatrices::sbox[256] =
{
    0x34, 0x5b,
    0x93, 0xc2
};

unsigned char PredefinedMatrices::getSBoxValue(unsigned char hexNumber) const {
    return sbox[hexNumber];
}
```

Comment: Always nice to see a better solution, but to be clear, this does not allow you to modify `sbox`, and it was not clear from your question that you wanted it to be read-only. You might also make `getSBoxValue` static, as nothing it does requires a `PredefinedMatrices` object either.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about it for a moment, you should either fill array item by item or use a buffer and copy data from it. Assume C++ support a syntax like this:

```
unsigned char myBuffer[256];
myBuffer = { 1, 2, ... };
```

Then do you think that compiler do something other than temp buffer and memcpy?
And if you fill array item by item, you have a larger code that affect your execution speed, so the only valid way to accomplish this is temp buffer + memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

> Assigning the values in the class directly won't work.

Yes, it will.

```
matrice[0] = 0x34;
matrice[1] = 0x5b;
...
```

> I don't want to do a memcpy of a temp matrice into the matrice I need either because of additional allocation time and memory consumption.

If you make the temp matrice `static unsigned char [256]` and define and initialise it in the constructor, there is no additional allocation time (it's initialised once, when the program is loaded, not each time the constructor is called), and the memory consumption, 256 bytes, is very likely to be lower than that of the code that fills each element of `matrice` separately.

jrok's comment to not use a raw array at all could be good, but it depends on why you're using the array.

Comment: I updated my initial post cause looks like people understood some things wrong. If I don't declare the variable in the class it won't be seen in the function. A solution would be to declare static unsigned char before the class and use it in the class but I was hoping to avoid making the code (more)ugly.

Comment: @MoraruLilian I'm not saying to declare `matrice` in the function, I'm saying you can declare `static unsigned char matriceInit[256]` in the constructor, and use `memcpy` to copy it to `matrice`. Other functions won't need to see `matriceInit`.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly assigning to the 256th element of the array when the last index is 255. Using a vector is by far the better approach than a raw array.  You can initialise your matrix in the constructor.

```
class PredefinedMatrices {
public:
    PredefinedMatrices();

    vector<unsigned char> matrice;
};

PredefinedMartices::PredefinedMatrices()
{
    matrice.resize(256,0);
    matrice[0] = 0x34;
    matrice[1] = 0x5b;
    matrice[2] = 0x93;
    matrice[3] = 0xc2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11, you can use regular initialisation syntax:

```
PredefinedMatrices::PredefinedMatrices()
  :sbox {
     0x34,
     0x5b,
     0x93,
     0xc2,
     /*...*/
    }
{}
```

Comment: Sure it does. Use the `-std=c++11` option on the command line.

Comment: Or, actually, the `-std=c++0x` option if you are on 4.6.

Comment: This must work on GCC 4.6, too. I think C++11 initialiser lists were supported since 4.4.

Comment: Does LLVM have the -Ofast flag somehow like GCC?

Comment: You were right. I was writing the application in Qt and I didn't know at the time that I have to manually specify in the project file to use C++11 with "CONFIG += c++11".